# Yorkshire Pudding Wraps

Tags: yorkshire-puddings

I saw a picture the other day of roast beef in a Yorkshire Pudding wrap and thought I'd give it a try sometime. The problem is that all advice I can find on how to make yorkshire puddings well points at making them rise and crisp, which probably wouldn't be great for making a wrap.

My thoughts are to make it with a slightly higher egg content by proportionally reducing the amount of milk but thought I'd pass it by this site to see what people think.

I saw the image [here](https://www.facebook.com/TheFoodBibleLB/photos/a.996913113664965.1073741827.996909263665350/1060390310650578/?type=3&theater):

[image: Beef Wrap]

Comment: Could you share that picture / a link with us? As I read it, it sounds selfcontradictory, a bit like "flat soufflé"

Comment: I added a link to where I saw it on Facebook.

Comment: That actually looks more like a Beef Wellington.

Comment: I should also mention that Yorkshire Pudding batter is rather similar to the German pfannkuchen, which may or may not puff up depending on how hot the pan is when you cook it.

Comment: Considering this is a restaurant's offering, I'd bet that it isn't actually a true "Yorkshire pudding" recipe. They have to be able to make these quickly and easily so I'd bet that they are pre-assembled.

Answer (score 7):

The way I found that works is:

- make a normal Yorkshire pudding batter mix.
- heat some oil (medium heat) in a large frying pan and turn on the grill to medium heat.
- treat the Yorkshire mix as a pancake - pour it into the pan, and cook until lightly browned on each side.
- once both sides are browned, pop the pan under the grill - this will cause the pudding pancake to start to rise and brown further. once one side is done, flip it and repeat.
- when you remove the pan from the grill, the pudding will start to deflate - it is soft enough to use as a wrap !

Answer (score 6):

My first recipe for Yorkshire pudding did not rise very well,  It was tasty, but a bit flat and somewhat custardy.  After googling many recipes and seeing what they had in common, I realized my original recipe had fewer eggs than most recipes, about 3/4 the amount (by volume) of either milk or flour.  When I increased the amount of eggs to equal the volume of the milk, I got tall, puffy, crispier Yorkshire pudding.

They do soften and fall a bit if you refrigerate them rather than eating them while hot.

Comment: I'll give this a try, it's the complete opposite of what I thought it might be. I might try this, then try returning the wrap to the oven after it's wrapped to crisp it more.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to make a Yorkshire pudding as normal in a square tin, then flatten risen pudding by gently rolling with a rolling pin, before filling.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it might be worth a try - I will give it a go: http://www.foodnetwork.co.uk/recipes/roast-beef-yorky-open-sandwich.html

The ratios for the batter are in the same ballpark as other yorkshire pudding recipes, and it's baked in a rectangular baking tray.

Comment: Hello Donnella,and welcome to our site. We are looking for answers which offer some explanation and are able to stand on their own. A link is not really that good, as it neither says much about why this recipe is supposed to work better than standard ones, nor will it be usable in a few years when the link breaks. It would be best to summarize the important points from there in your post, so readers can rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

You want your yorkshire pud to rise and crisp, if it doesn't rise it will be dense and tough. If it doesn't crip it tends to shrink and again get dense. I personally don't think using yorkshire pudding as a wrap material is a good idea, I would use leftovers that way but I wouldn't cook it specifically for that reason. Basically, for it to be pliable it needs to be a bit soggy, and who wants a soggy yorkshire pudding?

If you do want to make it and you're using UK recipes in the US remember that US egg sizes are smaller than the EU, a large UK egg is probably 20% bigger than a US large egg, maybe more, so scale up your egg accordingly. A handy trick when baking is to open the oven door for 10 seconds or so once the yorkies have risen to their maximum, this will let excess moisture out of the oven and help crisp them up.

Once they are out of the oven they will stay crispy for awhile, but you can get them pliable by covering them.